# OpenStack Mitaka login no longer possible

Tags: security, openstack, keystone

I can no longer log in to our open stack horizon dashboard. I tried to change the password with keystone (with `ADMIN_TOKEN`), but I got:

> Bad request (HTTP 400)

I didn't change the password, so another question is: Why I can not login?

**edit**

I found the following in the keystone logfile:

```
    2017-10-13 16:03:58.469 8767 DEBUG oslo_concurrency.lockutils [-] Acquired semaphore "singleton_lock" lock /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_concurrency/lockutils.py:215
2017-10-13 16:03:58.470 8767 DEBUG oslo_concurrency.lockutils [-] Releasing semaphore "singleton_lock" lock /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oslo_concurrency/lockutils.py:228
2017-10-13 16:03:58.470 8767 ERROR keystone.common.environment.eventlet_server [-] Could not bind to 0.0.0.0:35357
2017-10-13 16:03:58.470 8767 ERROR root [-] Failed to start the admin server
2017-10-13 16:03:58.470 8767 ERROR root Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-10-13 16:03:58.470 8767 ERROR root   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystone/server/eventlet.py", line 88, in serve
2017-10-13 16:03:58.470 8767 ERROR root     server.launch_with(launcher)
2017-10-13 16:03:58.470 8767 ERROR root   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystone/server/eventlet.py", line 54, in launch_with
2017-10-13 16:03:58.470 8767 ERROR root     self.server.listen()
2017-10-13 16:03:58.470 8767 ERROR root   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystone/common/environment/eventlet_server.py", line 110, in listen
2017-10-13 16:03:58.470 8767 ERROR root     backlog=backlog)
2017-10-13 16:03:58.470 8767 ERROR root   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/convenience.py", line 44, in listen
2017-10-13 16:03:58.470 8767 ERROR root     sock.listen(backlog)
2017-10-13 16:03:58.470 8767 ERROR root   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
2017-10-13 16:03:58.470 8767 ERROR root     return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
2017-10-13 16:03:58.470 8767 ERROR root error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
2017-10-13 16:03:58.470 8767 ERROR root
2017-10-13 16:03:58.471 8767 CRITICAL keystone [-] error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
2017-10-13 16:03:58.471 8767 ERROR keystone Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-10-13 16:03:58.471 8767 ERROR keystone   File "/usr/bin/keystone-all", line 10, in <module>
2017-10-13 16:03:58.471 8767 ERROR keystone     sys.exit(main())
2017-10-13 16:03:58.471 8767 ERROR keystone   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystone/cmd/all.py", line 39, in main
2017-10-13 16:03:58.471 8767 ERROR keystone     eventlet_server.run(possible_topdir)
2017-10-13 16:03:58.471 8767 ERROR keystone   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystone/server/eventlet.py", line 156, in run
2017-10-13 16:03:58.471 8767 ERROR keystone     serve(*servers)
2017-10-13 16:03:58.471 8767 ERROR keystone   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystone/server/eventlet.py", line 88, in serve
2017-10-13 16:03:58.471 8767 ERROR keystone     server.launch_with(launcher)
2017-10-13 16:03:58.471 8767 ERROR keystone   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystone/server/eventlet.py", line 54, in launch_with
2017-10-13 16:03:58.471 8767 ERROR keystone     self.server.listen()
2017-10-13 16:03:58.471 8767 ERROR keystone   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystone/common/environment/eventlet_server.py", line 110, in listen
2017-10-13 16:03:58.471 8767 ERROR keystone     backlog=backlog)
2017-10-13 16:03:58.471 8767 ERROR keystone   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/eventlet/convenience.py", line 44, in listen
2017-10-13 16:03:58.471 8767 ERROR keystone     sock.listen(backlog)
2017-10-13 16:03:58.471 8767 ERROR keystone   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
2017-10-13 16:03:58.471 8767 ERROR keystone     return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
2017-10-13 16:03:58.471 8767 ERROR keystone error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
2017-10-13 16:03:58.471 8767 ERROR keystone
```

From /var/log/apache2/keystone_wsgi_admin_error_ssl.log

```
[Fri Oct 13 12:50:04.955172 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 5185:tid 139847771273088] AH01906: <ip>:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Oct 13 12:50:05.108985 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 5186:tid 139847771273088] AH01906: <ip>:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
```

From /var/log/apache2/keystone_wsgi_main_error_ssl.log

```
[Fri Oct 13 12:50:04.934529 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 5185:tid 139847771273088] AH01906: <ip>:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Oct 13 12:50:05.088170 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 5186:tid 139847771273088] AH01906: <ip>:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
```

Comment: more information on the log would be great. Assuming you are using ubuntu and apache, you can take a look at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: I just added something from the logs (error.log from apache is empty).

Comment: Thanks and I would take a look at this: https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/66980/keystone-socket-error-errno-98-address-already-in-use/  More likely, your port `5000` or `35357` are in used by other services (maybe try `lsof -i -n -P` )

Comment: that doesn't work

Comment: sorry, not a keystone guy. either try to ask in IRC (#openstack-keystone) or upgrade your OpenStack to at least Newton since Mitaka is EOL: https://releases.openstack.org/

Comment: Apache should be serving this up, this usually happens when someone starts the keystone process even though it shouldn't be running. Usually you can fix this with something like `service keystone stop` , `service apache2 restart`, then see if you can get in. In older versions Keystone was standalone, which is why you see answers saying "restart keystone" and others saying "stop keystone + restart apache2."